# How to rotation DirectX11 FPS Game Camera?

Tags: directx, directx-11, frame-rate

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M8A1H7xWJcI&feature=youtu.be

watch that video.

My problem is left, right rotation is working well **but up, down rotation is not working properly (see video)**. I guess axis problem

That`s my source

GunObject Source
// Scale

```
XMMATRIX matScale = XMMatrixIdentity();
    matScale = XMMatrixScaling(m_Scaling.x, m_Scaling.y, m_Scaling.z);

    // rotation
    XMMATRIX matRoation = XMMatrixIdentity();
    matRoation *= XMMatrixRotationNormal(XMLoadFloat3(&XMFLOAT3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f)), m_fRotAngleY);
    matRoation *= XMMatrixRotationNormal(XMLoadFloat3(&vRight), m_fRotAngleX);

    // Translate
    XMMATRIX matTranslate = XMMatrixIdentity();
    matTranslate = XMMatrixTranslation(m_Pos.x, m_Pos.y, m_Pos.z);

    XMMATRIX matWorld = XMMatrixIdentity();
    matWorld = matScale * matRoation * matTranslate;

    XMStoreFloat4x4(&m_f4x4World, matWorld);
    XMStoreFloat4x4(&m_f4x4ViewProj, matViewProj);
    XMStoreFloat4x4(&m_f4x4WorldViewProj, matWorld * matViewProj);
```

FPSCamera View Matrix Source

```
XMVECTOR vRight    = XMLoadFloat3(&m_vRight);
    XMVECTOR vUp       = XMLoadFloat3(&m_vUp);
    XMVECTOR vLook     = XMLoadFloat3(&m_vLook);
    XMVECTOR vPosition = XMLoadFloat3(&m_vPosition);

    // 룩벡터와 업벡터, 횡벡터를 정규직교화 한다.
    vLook = XMVector3Normalize(vLook);
    vUp   = XMVector3Normalize( XMVector3Cross(vLook, vRight) );

    // 룩벡터와 업벡터는 이미 정규화과 되어 있으므로 횡벡터를 정규화 할 필요가 없다.
    vRight = XMVector3Cross(vUp, vLook);
    vRight = XMVector3Normalize(vRight);

    // 뷰행렬의 내용물을 설정한다.
    XMStoreFloat3(&m_vRight, vRight);
    XMStoreFloat3(&m_vUp, vUp);
    XMStoreFloat3(&m_vLook, vLook);

    m_f4x4View(0, 0) = m_vRight.x;
    m_f4x4View(1, 0) = m_vRight.y;
    m_f4x4View(2, 0) = m_vRight.z;
    m_f4x4View(3, 0) = -m_fOffsetX;
    //m_f4x4View(3, 0) = -XMVectorGetX(XMVector3Dot(vPosition, vRight));

    m_f4x4View(0, 1) = m_vUp.x;
    m_f4x4View(1, 1) = m_vUp.y;
    m_f4x4View(2, 1) = m_vUp.z;
    m_f4x4View(3, 1) = -XMVectorGetX(XMVector3Dot(vPosition, vUp));

    m_f4x4View(0, 2) = m_vLook.x;
    m_f4x4View(1, 2) = m_vLook.y;
    m_f4x4View(2, 2) = m_vLook.z;
    m_f4x4View(3, 2) = -m_fOffsetZ;

    m_f4x4View(0, 3) = 0.0f;
    m_f4x4View(1, 3) = 0.0f;
    m_f4x4View(2, 3) = 0.0f;
    m_f4x4View(3, 3) = 1.0f;

    m_vPosition.x -= m_fOffsetX;
    m_vPosition.z -= m_fOffsetZ;
    vPosition = XMLoadFloat3(&m_vPosition);

    XMFLOAT4X4 tempTranslateMatrix;
    XMStoreFloat4x4(&tempTranslateMatrix, XMMatrixIdentity());
    tempTranslateMatrix(3, 0) = -XMVectorGetX(XMVector3Dot(vPosition, vRight));
    tempTranslateMatrix(3, 1) = 0.0f;
    tempTranslateMatrix(3, 2) = -XMVectorGetX(XMVector3Dot(vPosition, vLook));;
    tempTranslateMatrix(3, 3) = 1.0f;

    XMMATRIX tempView = XMLoadFloat4x4(&m_f4x4View);
    tempView *= XMLoadFloat4x4(&tempTranslateMatrix);
    XMStoreFloat4x4(&m_f4x4View, tempView);
```

Comment: Looking at the video it looks like the problem is with the gun code. Since the gun should always be at the same screen position, you could simply render it without applying the camera rotation at all I would think.

Comment: `up, down rotation is now worked`? Now that's some sneaky problem!

Comment: @bigthewar Looks like yaw and pitch rotation works fine. What is your question?